# Finding distribution of function of random variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let X be a random variable uniformly distributed on [0,1] and let Y := [6X] + 1. Determine the distribution of Y and compute E(Y).

edit: It was pointed out that I neglected to account for the integer function part of the problem. Please fact check my work as if the problem stated $Y$ as $Y = 6X + 1$.

My attempt at solving:

$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = P(X\le (y-1)/6) = 1$ if $y \gt 7, y/6 - 1/6$ if $y \in [1,7], 0$ if $y\lt 1$.
Thus, $f_Y(y) = F_X'(y/6 - 1/6)(y/6 - 1/6)' = (1/6)*F_X(y/6-1/6) = 1/6 * 1/6$ if $y\in[1,7]$ and $0$ otherwise. But this is not a density.

I think that probably the correct answer is that Y~Uniform[1,7], but I would like to know where in my reasoning I went astray.

For $E[Y], E[Y] = E[6X + 1] = 6E[X] + 1 = 6(.5) + 1 = 4.$

Would like to know if my answer is correct and if not, why. Thank you

Comment: “$[6x] \neq 6x$”, first things first.  It means the integer part of $6x$.  Therefore, $Y$ is a discrete, not continuous, random variable.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you, I edited the OP to mention that. I am going to post a secondary thread with the problem being Y = [X] + 1. For this one, I would like to solve it as Y = X + 1.

Comment: @Alborz You mean Y= **6** X+1?

Comment: @callculus42 Yes. Sorry

Comment: @Alborz Even so, the distribution is incorrect.  Your density does not integrate to 1 on $[1, 7]$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I pointed that out. The point of the post is to find where in my reasoning I went astray.

Comment: @callculus42 I am looking to find where in my reasoning I went wrong

Comment: @Alborz What are your reasonings for your steps?

Comment: @callculus42 I showed my work above

Comment: @Alborz Yes, but I cannot comprehend your steps. I think I'm not the only one. You haven't told us why you have made these steps. Anyway, I wish you good luck.

Comment: @Alborz Overall, your reasoning is a little messy (this could also be due to you do not want to spend much time on typesetting). It seems that you already found that $F_Y(y) = y/6 - 1/6$ when $y \in [1, 7]$, which allows you to evaluate $F_Y'(y) = (y/6 - 1/6)' = 1/6$ directly, instead of using the chain rule.

Comment: @Zhanxiong that cleared up my confusion thanks